# Macro gets current user macro not contacts

Tags: c#, kentico

I am trying to create a custom module which stores some text that contains some macro based on a recipient list. The recipient list is from a specific contact group.

I have a rich text editor with text "Hi {%Contact.ContactFirstName%}" that needs to be converted to actual first name based on the contact and stored it in a table.

First, I'll get the emails of the members of a contact group and put it in an array.

Then, I used the Send(IssueInfo issue, string recipients) method and pass the emails to the method resolve the macro and store it in the table.

However, the values that are stored in the table is the first name of the current user (which is myself) instead of the contact's first name.

Below is the code to get all the members in a contact group.

```
 var members = ContactInfoProvider.GetContacts().WhereIn("ContactID", ContactGroupMemberInfoProvider.GetRelationships().Column("ContactGroupMemberRelatedID").WhereEquals("ContactGroupMemberType", 0).WhereIn("ContactGroupMemberContactGroupID", IssueContactGroupInfoProvider.GetIssueContactGroups().Column("ContactGroupID").WhereEquals("IssueID", issue.IssueID))).WhereNotEmpty("ContactMobilePhone");

foreach (var member in members)
{
   email += ValidationHelper.GetString(member.GetValue("ContactEmail"), "") + ";";
}
```

Here's the code to resolve the macro and to store inside a table. Most of it just from Email Marketing module code.

```
 public void Send(SMSIssueInfo issue, string recipients)
    {
        if (issue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(issue));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipients))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(recipients));
        SMSInfo newsletterInfo = SMSInfoProvider.GetSMSInfo(issue.IssueSMSID);
        if (newsletterInfo == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("SMS not found.");
        SiteInfo siteInfo = SiteInfoProvider.GetSiteInfo(newsletterInfo.SMSSiteID);
        if (siteInfo == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("SMS site not found.");
        string[] strArray = recipients.Split(new char[1]
        {
        ';'
        }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        SMSTemplateInfo SMSTemplate = SMSTemplateInfoProvider.GetSMSTemplateInfo(issue.IssueTemplateID);


        foreach (string smsrecipients in strArray)
        {

            string str = "";
            str = GetEmailBody(issue, newsletterInfo, SMSTemplate, null, false, siteInfo.SiteName, null, null, null);

            SMSIssueHelper issueHelper = new SMSIssueHelper();

            if (issueHelper.LoadDynamicFields(null, newsletterInfo, null, issue, true, siteInfo.SiteName, null, null, null))
            {
                //.Subject = issueHelper.ResolveDynamicFieldMacros(message.Subject, newsletterInfo, issue);
                str = issueHelper.ResolveDynamicFieldMacros(str, newsletterInfo, issue);
            }

            string absolute = LinkConverter.ConvertToAbsolute(str, SMSIssueHelper.GetNewsletterLinksBaseUrl(newsletterInfo, siteInfo));

            var contacts = ContactInfoProvider.GetContactInfo(smsrecipients);

            SMSQueueInfo smsQueue = new SMSQueueInfo();

            smsQueue.SmsLastModified = DateTime.Now;
            smsQueue.SmsScheduledSendTime = DateTime.Now;
            smsQueue.SmsTo = contacts.ContactMobilePhone;
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsSubject", ValidationHelper.GetString(issue.GetValue("IssueSubject"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsBody", str);
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsSiteID", ValidationHelper.GetString(issue.GetValue("IssueSiteID"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsCreated", DateTime.Now);
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsIsScheduled", 0);
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsIssueID", ValidationHelper.GetString(issue.GetValue("IssueID"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsClientID", ValidationHelper.GetString(contacts.GetValue("ContactClientID"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsClientName", ValidationHelper.GetString(issue.GetValue("ContactFirstName"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsSenderID", MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.UserID);
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsKey", ValidationHelper.GetString(newsletterInfo.GetValue("SMSKey"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsFrom", ValidationHelper.GetString(newsletterInfo.GetValue("SMSSenderNumber"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsClientName", ValidationHelper.GetString(contacts.GetValue("ContactFirstName"), ""));
            smsQueue.SetValue("SmsStatus", 0);

            SMSQueueInfoProvider.SetSMSQueueInfo(smsQueue);
        }


    }
```

The expected result would be the first name of the contact that are inside the contact group for example "Hi John" and not the user that clicked the "Save" button.

I am on Kentico 10.0.42.

Comment: How would issueHelper know anything about Contact? In other words I think macro resolver has no idea about Contact context. Or it uses current Contact which Kentico created for your account.

Comment: Any suggestion on what I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Peter, I used the same approach in some of our projects. Basically, all you need to do in code in order to get the email's text:

1. Get email template text containing Macros (it can contain both standard and custom macros)
2. Register custom data sources for macro resolver
3. Resolve macroses and then you can send the email!

A small addition, it is possible to use complex data structures as macro data sources. Here is the example of populating event (Event page type) and attendee (ContactInfo module class) data dynamically:

```
    public static string GetEventEmailText(string emailTemplateName, string contactEmail)
    {
        var eventItem = EventDocumentService.GetCachedItems().FirstOrDefault();
        var contact = ContactInfoProvider.GetContactInfo(contactEmail);

        var resolver = MacroResolver.GetInstance();
        resolver.SetNamedSourceData("Event", eventItem);
        resolver.SetNamedSourceData("Attendee", contact);
        resolver.Settings.EncodeResolvedValues = true;

        var emailTemplate = EmailTemplateProvider.GetEmailTemplate(emailTemplateName, SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
        return emailTemplate == null ? string.Empty : resolver.ResolveMacros(emailTemplate.TemplateText);
    }
```

And in the email template, I use these macros:

```
Hi, {% Attendee.ContactFirstName %} {% Attendee.ContactLastName %}

Your event begins: {% Event.Date.ToString() %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitry & Peter, this solved my problem. Now I understand that I need to resolve the macro against the contactInfo. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the correct context (DataSource) for you macro resolver. Here is [the article how to do it in the email](https://www.kehrendev.com/blog/brenden-kehren/october-2015/using-the-macroresolver-api-with-email-templates) that should give you the idea